# Updating data sets from Online databases/Webservice

Tags: shell-script, python, mysql

I want to have an idea as to how to update the data regularly from the source, if its stored locally in your server or local machine.Lets say MySQL database.

Source:It will be a webservice data repository. Data sets: An online data repository has a number of data sets.

I want to know which data sets have been updated and what changes have been made.

I have done queries in MySQL, but not done anything like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is pretty general. The dba.sx site would be better for this, but is probably too general even for them. Suggestion: take it to the dba.sx chat and talk to them. Either they can answer your questions, or they may assist you in producing a clear question (or questions).

Comment: I posted this question here(http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73575/updating-data-sets-from-online-databases-webservice).Do you have any general idea on what this design would be called?I have read on Database replication which synchronizes the databases.

Comment: If this is a bioinformatics application, you could also ask in a bioinformatics forum.